# Searching first condition first and only if not available then second condition

Tags: oracle

I am writing an SQL query where the query should first search the first value, and only if this value is missing the query should search for the second value.

I have two tables. One of these tables contains the modification date (this is not always filled and can be `null`) and a creation date which is always filled.

Now what I want is that the query first looks in the table with the modification date and only if it is `null` looks at the table with the creation date.

Example of the query:

```
Select *
  from all_articles
  where to_char(modification_date, 'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')-1 
-- if this is an empty record then  
to_char(creation_date, 'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')-1
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: you want us to write query ? tell us what you tried ?

Comment: the best advice i can give you to make this question better for people reading now and in the future is to add a very simple example of the 2 tables with a couple of rows of data. then add what the desired output should be, so it's clear what you have to work from and what you expect the output to be. it would be even better if you added the code you've tried so we can advise why it's not working. without that, you're question is likely to be downvoted and closed, and you won't get the help you need.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all the major RDBMS' available have in built functions to handle such a situation. 
The Oracle DB has NVL function which works as follows:
NVL(Modified_dt, Create_dt);

The above will return Modified_dt column data by default. However, if that isn't available, it will return Create_dt.

See here for details:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Oracle has supported the more powerful and standards-compliant Coalesce() function for many years now as an alternative to the proprietary and limited Nvl(). I'd suggest that you use that instead.

Comment: + to @DavidAldridge : coalesce is way better in most cases and is supported by indices

Comment: @simon -- not sure that there is a difference in indexability between Coalesce and Nvl.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: they are both indexable (when you have a functional index), but if you have a normal index on a raw field `f1` then `coalesce(f1,123)` will use that index; `nvl(f1,123)` won't use it